# How do I effectively utilize long-range characters?

Tags: marvel-vs-capcom-infinite

**How do I deal substantial damage using characters who rely primarily on long-range attacks?**

Some characters in Marvel vs Capcom Infinite are decidedly long-range characters, such as Hawkeye and Arthur.  They have a variety of different projectile attacks to lock down and deal damage to opponents.

However, various changes from the previous game seem to have resulted in a big nerf to projectile-heavy gameplay.  While **projectile chip damage** was infamously high in UMvC3, it **is now extremely low** to the point of being negligible.  Defenders can also use **Timed Advancing Guard** to **reflect projectiles** back at the attacker.  Since reflected projectiles negate other projectiles, this can even effectively counter multi-shot moves such as Hawkeye's Greyhound ("Triple Arrow").

In my experience thus far, being at a full-screen distance and shooting projectiles with these projectile characters has been wholly ineffective.  Opponents would simply block and/or reflect, and could keep this up "all day" without repercussion, forcing melee combat.  **Are projectile heavy tactics simply no longer effective?**  If they are, what is the key?